# Get if command is multiline in a ZLE widget

Tags: zsh, zle

How can I get whether the command being typed is multiline?

$CONTEXT can determine when at a secondary prompt like:

```
$ echo 'hello
quote> world'
```

But how can I determine when there's a newline like:

```
$ echo 'hello
world'
```

(Doable in vi mode or with self-insert-unmeta)

I need this info in a ZLE widget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The complete content of the logical input line is in [`BUFFER`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-BUFFER).

```
[[ $BUFFER == *$'\n'* ]]
```